# React Component methods invoke itself without calling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This photo carousel works fine.It changes photos in every 5 second.
My question is How does `setInterval(this.nextGP, 5000);` invoke itself without calling  `  componentDidMount ? 
Here is :

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.nextGP, 5000);
  },
```

In javascript :
function called inside another function does not invoke until we call the outer function .

```
       function outer(){
          anotherFunction();
    };
    anotherFunction(){
     alert("hello");
}
outer(); // We call outer to invoke anotherFunction .
```

But In react above `setInterval()` invokes without calling outer function.

=============== The Entire Code Here  ===========================

```
  var GUINEAPATHS = [
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-1.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-2.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-3.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-4.jpg'
];

var GuineaPigs = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { currentGP: 0 };
  },

  nextGP: function () {
    var current = this.state.currentGP;
    var next = ++current % GUINEAPATHS.length;
    this.setState({ currentGP: next });
  },

  interval: null,

  componentDidMount: function () {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.nextGP, 5000);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },

  render: function () {
    var src = GUINEAPATHS[this.state.currentGP];
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Cute Guinea Pigs</h1>
        <img src={src}/>

    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <GuineaPigs />, 
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

The *lifecycle* functions such as *componentDidMount, shouldComponentUpdate* etc are called by React itself when creating and rendering your component.

So *componentDidMount* will be called when the component is first created by React; this will kick your *setInterval* off.

Comment: Thanks for help ! In this example , Are those all lifecycle functions except render ? nextGP,  componentDidMount,   componentWillUnmount ? When I create component , It invokes all the functions ? (from top to bottom)

Comment: The ones I mentioned are: they're described here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Comment: React will call them as it goes through the stages of creating your component and (for example) when it's about to receive a change in its properties. render too will be called by React when it deems that the component needs to be re-rendered (eg when its props have changed).

Comment: Thank you very much you save my life .Those were  built-in functions.I thought this componentDidMount is an orndinary function name.Thank you again !

Answer (score 1):

From [`React Spec`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.